# Casting Class Type Dynamically in fragment

Tags: android, fragment

In fragment we have code like below :

```
((DashboardActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentSession())
```

Where we cast `getActivity` to class name in above example with `DashboardActivity` but I want to cast dynamically with class conical string name

I have tried with :

```
private Class<?> mSupperActivity;
if (StringClassname != null) {
    try {
        mSupperActivity = Class.forName(StringClassname);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

((mSupperActivity) getActivity())
```

But it gives me error that unknown class type.

Any hint or help would be great.

Comment: That's an odd piece of code. Why do you want to do this? It's probably erroring because you need the package name

Comment: i have frament which is common for few activies in my application but everytime i hv to cast (ClassType) it does not work for all activies.

Comment: This seems like you'd still need to catch a ClassCastException. Might I suggest you extend a common class or interface for all these classes you are trying to cast? I'm still lost as to why they need cast in the first place

Comment: i tried catching class cast exception but it didnt help it still knowing error, for  extending common class that solution might not work in my case since many activity hv different base class.

Comment: You should only have `AppCompatActivity` as the base class. Just extend that and implement your method there and extend your custom Activity in your other Activities. You can then freely cast to that Activity

Answer (score 2):

Introduce an interface:

```
public interface SessionAware {
    Session getCurrentSession();
}
```

implement it in all Activities that use the Fragment:

```
public class DashboardActivity implements SessionAware
```

and cast the Activity to the interface type to call the method:

```
((SessionAware) getActivity()).getCurrentSession();
```